# Using Lambda to insert derived attribute into IQueryable dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda

I have the following query:

```
IQueryable<BarcodeQuery> barcodes = db.Barcodes.Select(b => new BarcodeQuery
{
    id = b.id,
    category_id = b.category_id,
    ...
    checkout = b.Checkouts.Select(c => new CheckoutChild
    {
        id = c.id,
        loanee_id = c.loanee_id,
        ...
    })
    .Where(c => c.datein == null)
    .FirstOrDefault()
});
```

And so on. It's based on this model:

```
public class BarcodeQuery
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int category_id { get; set; }
    ...
    public CheckoutChild checkout { get; set; }
    public CheckoutStatus checkoutStatus { get; set; }
}
```

My question is about `CheckoutStatus` down there at the bottom. It looks like this:

```
public class CheckoutStatus
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int daysUntilDue { get; set; }
    public int daysOverdue { get; set; }
}
```

All of those values are derived from information I get from the query--none of them are in the database itself. What is the best way of inserting the `CheckoutStatus` values into each `barcode` record?

I have a function that creates the `CheckoutStatus` values themselves, I just don't know how to get them into the `barcode` records.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `b` has just be created with `new`, how can `b.Checkouts` contain something? I do not really understadn what you are trying to do.

EF is converting the lambda expression into a SQL statement. Therefore you can only use expressions that can actually be translated to SQL. Just query the barcodes from the DB and then add the missing information to the barcodes returned in a loop.

```
var barcodes = db.Barcodes.Select(...).ToList();
foreach (Barcode b in barcodes) {
    b.Checkouts = ...
}
```